# Romanian vowel sound changes

Tags: tikz-trees, linguistics

I am new to LaTeX. This question is tree-related. Are there any TikZ-tree-related questions that can be combined to reproduce this following image?
[image]

Original image is from [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Vowel_changes_from_Latin_to_Italian.png/320px-Vowel_changes_from_Latin_to_Italian.png). If it is poorly written, feel free to close it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this exact question was asked the other day then deleted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a one-off diagram, David's answer works well enough, although he should probably have used picture mode rather than `\bigvee` for the connections. :) But if you're doing more sound changes than just this one, it might be helpful to have a macro.

Here's a version using `forest` which inputs each change with a command `\pcorr`:

```
\pcorr{top vowel}[second-top vowel]{bottom vowel}
```

The `*` version of the command flips the tree to represent splits as well as mergers:

```
\pcorr*{top vowel}[first bottom vowel]{second bottom vowel}
```

And a `\pslash` command to add the phoneme slashes and labels:

```
\pslash[top label][bottom label]
```

To make input slightly easier I've wrapped the labels and closing slash into an environment:

```
 \begin{soundchange}{top label}{bottom label} ... \end{soundchange}
```

Here's the full example (process with LuaLaTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\forestset{pcorr/.style={inner sep=1pt,outer sep=1pt},
    pcorr up/.style={for tree={pcorr,grow=north,anchor=south}},
    pcorr down/.style={for tree={pcorr,grow=south,anchor=south},for next leaf={baseline}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pcorr}{smom}{
\IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {\begin{forest}pcorr up[#4[#2]]\end{forest}}
    {\IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\begin{forest}pcorr down[#2[#3][#4]]\end{forest}}
    {\begin{forest}pcorr up[#4[#3][#2]]\end{forest}}
    }       
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pslash}{oo}{%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\begin{forest}pcorr up[#2,[#1,no edge]]\end{forest}~}
    \begin{forest}pcorr up[/[/,no edge]]\end{forest}
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{soundchange}{mm}
{\pslash[#1][#2]}
{\pslash\par}

\begin{document}
\begin{soundchange}{Latin}{Proto-Romanian}
\pcorr{iː}{i}
\pcorr{i}[eː]{e}
\pcorr{e}{ɛ}
\pcorr{aː}[a]{a}
\pcorr{o}[oː]{o}
\pcorr{u}[uː]{u}
\end{soundchange}

\bigskip
\pslash[Middle English][Modern English]
\pcorr*{u}[ʌ]{ʊ}
\pslash

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Neat, but does the first `baseline` have any effect if the second is always executed?

Comment: @cfr No, it doesn't; I really just added it to make the code more logical. I had had one originally. Maybe I should just take it out. It doesn't really matter whether it's in the first or second node.

Comment: I suppose I think if there are two, I expect them to be doing something to align the nodes as opposed to the tree. Since they act on the tree, I don't really see it's more logical to have two ;).

Comment: @cfr I've made a conceptually cleaner solution which puts the `baseline` as part of the main tree options using `for leaves`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes. I didn't see your comment before answering in chat (but I saw the code). I'd suggest `pcorr down/.style={for tree={pcorr,grow=south,anchor=south},for next leaf={baseline}}` instead. That will only execute `baseline` once, whereas your current version will do so four times.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! That is better.

Comment: In this case, you could also just do `!1.baseline` but the meaning is then rather more opaque.

Answer (score 1):

`ː` is U+02D0 MODIFIER LETTER TRIANGULAR COLON  which is available in several fonts, eg this, with lualatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
  Latin & / & iː & i & eː & e & aː & a & o & oː & u & uː & / \\
    &
    & $|$ &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bigvee$} &
    $|$ &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bigvee$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bigvee$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\bigvee$} &
\\
Proto-Romanian & 
/ &
i & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{e} & 
ɛ &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{a} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{o} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{u} &/
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```